# c# type a = new type(b);

Tags: c#, object, constructor

In C# how are new object instances created that are copies of existing ones instead of default ones.

For example:

```
door a = new door();
door b = a;
door c = new door(a);
b.open();
a.is_open(); // yes
b.is_open(); // yes
c.is_open(); // no
```

edit: In case it's usefull, I made this after accepting the answer and will post it here.

```
public class copyable // inherit from this to make you'r object copyable
{
    public heading copy()
    {
        return (heading)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Comment: this all depends on what `door` is - is it a reference or value type? What does the constructor do that accepts another `door` ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing a parameter in a constructor there is no easy way to create a copy besides copying all the fields. You could use `door c = a.MemberwiseClone();` to create a shallow copy, or roll your own.

Comment: I see MemberwiseClone is protected, this means everything that needs to be copyable needs a copy member function that uses MemberwiseClone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a coppy of a object, you have to create a copy constructor or inherent them off [iclonable](http://en.csharp-online.net/ICloneable)

Comment: Gotta disappoint you, but ICloneable is [considered obsolete/bad practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx)

Comment: Well my first answer wass the copy constructor. That is what i always use

Comment: +1 @ClausJørgensen but I think it's funny that the article is titled "Should we Obsolete ICloneable" and it's from 2004 and now we are in 2011 :-)